# How do I trim characters at the beginning of an NSString on iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have this `NSString`:

> Item 22345: Baseballs

How do I trim the `Item 22345:` part out so I just have `Baseballs` left. Note that the item # can change. So it could be `Item 2399` next time.

Comment: Have you looked at the docs for `NSString`? There are plenty of methods for finding substrings and extracting substrings.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably several ways to achieve that. If you always have ": " between, you can do it this way:

```
NSArray *items = [itemString componentsSeparatedByString:@": "];
NSString *itemName = [items lastObject];
```

Comment: Why split the string? Its inefficient for this use. Find the range of `@": "` then extract the needed substring based on the range. Too many people jump to `componentsSeparatedByString:`.

Comment: Something like `[string substringFromIndex:[string rangeOfString:@": "].location + 2];` You can find all the string splitting methods in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)

Comment: Sure as I started, there are several ways to do that. Splitting is one option - I don't think it's too expensive.